# Error when mass updating Attributes

Tags: magento2, php, php-7, php-7.1

Trying to mass update some attributes of products but when I try to open the update attributes form I get an error..

any ideas of the cause?

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset:
>   32000 in
>   /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/action/inventory.phtml
>   on line 37
>
> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 32000 in
>   /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/action/inventory.phtml
>   on line 37 #1 include() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]

Answer (score 20):

A flaw in the migration script left the setting empty for:

**Stores -> Settings: Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Product Stock Options: Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart**

Change the quantity to `1` for "**ALL GROUPS**" and save.